# WPF XAML Binding Nested Object Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have several Classes that contain Classes and need to access their properties in the WPF Forms. I am trying to Bind properties of "ppl" to controls. Using Path=ppl.wife apparently is not correct. (obviously I am new to WPF)

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        department = "Rock Truck Drivers";

        emp = new employee();
        emp.first = "Fred";
        emp.last = "Flintsone";
        emp.address = "Bedrock";
        emp.ppl.kid = "Pebbles";
        emp.ppl.wife = "Wilma";

        DataContext = emp;
    }
}
public class employee
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public other ppl = new other(); 
}
public class other
{
    public string kid { get; set; }
    public string wife { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
    <TextBox
        Width="120"
        Height="23"
        Margin="222,119,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Text="{Binding first, Mode=TwoWay}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBox
        Width="120"
        Height="23"
        Margin="222,155,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Text="{Binding Path=last, Mode=TwoWay}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBox
        Name="TextWife"
        Width="120"
        Height="23"
        Margin="222,196,0,0"
        Text="{Binding XPath=ppl.wife, Mode=TwoWay}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.  The first is that your binding uses `XPath=ppl.wife`.  It should be `Path=ppl.wife`.  You could also leave off the `Path=` part as well (like you did with the binding to `first`).

The second issue is that binding in WPF generally doesn't work on fields (see [the Binding Source overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview)).

> **common language runtime (CLR) objects**
>
> **You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as indexers**, of any common language runtime (CLR) object. The binding engine uses CLR reflection to get the values of the properties. Alternatively, objects that implement ICustomTypeDescriptor or have a registered TypeDescriptionProvider also work with the binding engine.

If you change your `ppl` field into a property, binding will work.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Other Ppl { get; } = new Other(); // Ppl is now a property rather than a field
}
public class Other
{
    public string Kid { get; set; }
    public string Wife { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfect, thank you. I actually knew about fields vs properties but managed to miss this one completely.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped you out!